# How to remove labels and arrows to the next plot in script

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following Gnuplot script:

```
set label "Threshold"  at first  1.03, first  -15
set arrow from graph 0,first -13 to graph 1, first -13 nohead lt 0 lw 5 

plot [1:12][] pot_t(x) t "up"  w lines ls 1
```

Plot this:
[image]

with a horizontal line at -13.

If I add a second plot in the script

```
plot [5:20][] pot_t(x) t "up"  w lines ls 1
```

[image]
the horizontal line `arrow` and `label` still there.

How could I remove the label `threshold` and the dashed horizontal line?

Regards

Comment: Did you try `unset label` and `unset arrow` right before the `plot ...` statement?

Comment: please remove all unnecessary stuff from your script for posting. Minimal examples!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Labels and arrows stay in every subsequent plot until you explicitly remove them, like practically *all* gnuplot settings.

You can find out the identifier number of each of them with `show label` / `show arrow` and remove them via `unset`.

```
set label 5 at 1,1 "Labeltext" # Explicitly give the label an id number
plot x   # Here's a label
unset label 5
plot x   # And it's gone
```

You can keep track of your arrows and labels by giving them an id number (`5` in the above example).

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was a simple question but I was trying the unset without the number and it did not work. Regards

Comment: `unset label` *does* remove all labels, at least on gnuplot 5.2pl3. Do you have a very old version at work?

Comment: I did not use `unset`, I was wirtting `set no label`. The command was incorrect.

Comment: @pablo Well, `help set label` would've told you all you need to know. ;-)